# Cardview is ok in preview but does not appear on mobile

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="com.example.taksi.cardview.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="GRID LAYOUT"
            android:textSize="34sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/me_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Me"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/family_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Family"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/lovely_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Lovely"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/team_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Team"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the preview it is like:

[image]

But when it runs on mobile it  is like:

[image]

When I run it my mobile, it's look like the second picture. But I want to get the same output like the preview window. But it doesn't appear on my mobile. I make some changes ,but nothing is changed. The output remains same as before. What can do now? Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you doing anything in the activivty ??

Comment: show your java code. And you should avod using nested weight in your layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="#fcfcfc"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/ll">
<LinearLayout
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/bankcardId"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"    
                android:src="@drawable/your_image"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Me"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:src="@drawable/your_image"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Family"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove grid layout and use Linear layout than place your cardviews